# How to prevent rsyslog from logging cron tasks to /var/log/syslog using additional config

Tags: cron, docker, rsyslog

I have a Docker image for cron tasks. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron rsyslog

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN chmod 0777 /var/log/cron.log

COPY ./app /var/www/app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

COPY 02-cron.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/02-cron.conf

CMD service rsyslog start && service cron start && tail -f /dev/null
```

By default rsyslog logs cron to /var/log/syslog. I want to log cron to a separate file /var/log/cron.log.

rsyslog's master config /etc/rsyslog.conf has the following lines:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
```

I want to disable logging cron to /var/log/syslog and enable logging it to /var/log/cron.log by adding one more config /etc/rsyslog.d/02-cron.conf:

```
*.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                          /var/log/cron.log
```

But the result is that cron logs to both /var/log/syslog and /var/log/cron.log.

Answer (score 1):

Line in you config:

```
*.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
```

make it like this:

```
*.*;cron.none,auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
```

to stop `cron` from logging in `syslog`

And also you can add dash (`-`) in front of the path for `cron` log to avoid flush of buffers on every write. So your cron line to become:

```
cron.*                          -/var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: I've done everything as you suggested but logs are still written in two files.

Comment: @femalemoustache, have you restart `rsyslog` after you change the config?

Comment: yes, I stop and remove container and image before each change.